# Why does getaddrinfo not return all IP Addresses?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to get all IP Addresses for: earth.all.vpn.airdns.org
In Python:

```
def hostnamesToIps(hostnames):
  ip_list = []

  for hostname in hostnames:
      try:
          ais = socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, None)
          for result in ais:
              #print (result[4][0])
              ip_list.append(result[-1][0])
      except:
          eprint("Unable to get IP for hostname: " + hostname)

return list(set(ip_list))
```

(fyi eprint is a function for printing error). 
The Output gives me 29 Addresses.

But when i do:

```
nslookup earth.all.vpn.airdns.org
```

I get about 100 entrys.

How to achieve this in python? Why i am not getting all entrys with "getaddrinfo"?

This behaviour only appears using windows (python 3). When i am executing the code on my Linux (python 2.7) it gives me the same result as using nslookup.

**info:** As in the answer explained it does not depend on the system.

---

Without changing anything the results of nslookup and getaddrinfo are the same now.

Comment: On my machine this code returns 160 IPs, which is the same output of `nslookup`.

Comment: Okay, thats weird. Is it possible that getaddrinfo uses another dns to look up the ip's?

Comment: One way you can try to figure this out is just have a file `r = set([result[-1][0] for result in getaddrinfo('earth.all.vpn.airdns.org', None)])` (with the `from socket import getaddrinfo`) and run `strace python file.py` and see what system calls it makes.  You should see `connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.2.1")}, 16) = 0` which corresponds to the IP address of the nameserver python used.  Compare that to `nslookup` and make sure you the same servers are used (DNS = port 53).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools like `dig`, `host` and `nslookup` query the default DNS server directly using UDP/TCP and their own implementation of DNS queries, whereas Python's `socket` module uses the DNS lookup interface of the operating system, which usually uses a more sophisticates lookup mechanism involving e.g. a dns cache, a host file, domain suffixes, link-local name resolution etc.

`strace` shows that Python's `socket.getaddrinfo` ends up using  a netlink (AF_NETLINK) socket, to query the system for the DNS lookup (Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04). `nslookup` however, reads the default DNS server from `/etc/resolv.conf` and opens a UDP socket on port 53.

I think there are two reason why you are getting a different entry count:

1. The DNS entries are quite volatile a may change at any instant
2. Python returns cached entries provided by the system's DNS cache whereas `nslookup` always retrieves "fresh" results.

Furthermore, `nslookup` might produce slightly different DNS queries than the system resolver (producing another answer). That could be checked with Wireshark, but I will leave that for now.

<strike>Another issue could be the truncation of DNS responses when UPD is used. If there is a large number of entries, they won't fit in a single UDP package, so the answer contains a truncation flag. It depends on the client to re-send the DNS query over a TCP socket in order to retrieve all results.</strike> (Truncated answers are actually empty).

**Edit:** A note on caching / volatile

Even if the mismatch is not due to your local DNS cache, it may be due to server-side caching. I tried several DNS servers and all gave different results for that particular name. That means that they are not in sync due to DNS changes within the time-to-live (TTL).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The described behaviour seems to appear only when i use my windows system. Anyways python shouldnt have cached these entries since i was executing nslookup and the getaddrinfo at nearly the same time (and didnt execute a getaddrinfo with the hostname before), so it seems to be a problem with windows and python 3.

Comment: @PhilipB On windows, you can check with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Python does not do any caching. It's the OS.

Comment: Executing the code now gives me the same result (different order since i am using set obviously) without changing anything. 
Still this is a really strange behaviour. And i don't think it is caused by caching. And i don't really think that the entries are volatile. A friend of mine sent me this: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/01/03/getaddrinfo-with-round-robin-dns-and-happy-eyeballs/ maybe it has something to do with it.

Comment: See my edit about response truncation. On my machine, nslookup yields around 160 results, whereas `getaddrinfo` returns 480 entries.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have one additional question: getaddrinfo returns 160 entries with my system. How to tell it to use tcp socket?

Comment: The bits on UDP/TCP are actually wrong. I checked again and it seems that the DNS entries are volatile indeed.  (see my edit)